# Log analysis to query logs based on a log message

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have a Java application that ouputs log in the format

timestamp UUID1 some information
timestamp UUID1 some more information
timestamp UUID1 x = 1

timestamp UUID2 some information
timestamp UUID2 some more information
timestamp UUID2 x = 2

timestamp UUID3 some information
timestamp UUID3 some more information
timestamp UUID3 x = 1

I want to implement a log analysis framework using Elsatic Search, LogStash and Kibana. Is it possible to get the logs only according to X value?

For example:-

If I query X = 1, I should get only the following logs.

timestamp UUID1 some information
timestamp UUID1 some more information
timestamp UUID1 x = 1
timestamp UUID3 some information
timestamp UUID3 some more information
timestamp UUID3 x = 1

If I query X = 2, I should get only the following logs.

timestamp UUID2 some information
timestamp UUID2 some more information
timestamp UUID2 x = 2

I am in control of the log message format. If it is not directly popssible to do this query, I can change the message format also.

UPDATE 1:

I will be a little more specific.

The following are my log statements.

```
    MDC.put("uuid", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    logger.info("Assigning value to the variable : {}", name);
    this.setVal(value.getVal());
    logger.info("{} = {}", name, value.getVal());
    logger.info("Assigned value {} to the variable : {}", value.getVal(),
            name);
    MDC.clear();
```

I received the log statements in Logstash using UDP. And I am getting the messages like.

```html
{
     "@timestamp" => "2015-04-01T10:23:37.846+05:30",
       "@version" => 1,
        "message" => "Assigning value to the variable : X",
    "logger_name" => "com.example.logstash.Variable",
    "thread_name" => "pool-1-thread-1",
          "level" => "INFO",
    "level_value" => 20000,
       "HOSTNAME" => "pnibinkj-W7-1",
           "uuid" => "ab17b842-8348-4474-98e4-8bc2b8dd6781",
           "host" => "127.0.0.1"
}
{
     "@timestamp" => "2015-04-01T10:23:37.846+05:30",
       "@version" => 1,
        "message" => "Assigning value to the variable : Y",
    "logger_name" => "com.example.logstash.Variable",
    "thread_name" => "pool-1-thread-2",
          "level" => "INFO",
    "level_value" => 20000,
       "HOSTNAME" => "pnibinkj-W7-1",
           "uuid" => "d5513e4c-de3b-4144-87e4-87b077ac8056",
           "host" => "127.0.0.1"
}
{
     "@timestamp" => "2015-04-01T10:23:37.862+05:30",
       "@version" => 1,
        "message" => "Y = 1",
    "logger_name" => "com.example.logstash.Variable",
    "thread_name" => "pool-1-thread-2",
          "level" => "INFO",
    "level_value" => 20000,
       "HOSTNAME" => "pnibinkj-W7-1",
           "uuid" => "d5513e4c-de3b-4144-87e4-87b077ac8056",
           "host" => "127.0.0.1"
}
{
     "@timestamp" => "2015-04-01T10:23:37.863+05:30",
       "@version" => 1,
        "message" => "X = 1",
    "logger_name" => "com.example.logstash.Variable",
    "thread_name" => "pool-1-thread-1",
          "level" => "INFO",
    "level_value" => 20000,
       "HOSTNAME" => "pnibinkj-W7-1",
           "uuid" => "ab17b842-8348-4474-98e4-8bc2b8dd6781",
           "host" => "127.0.0.1"
}
{
     "@timestamp" => "2015-04-01T10:23:37.863+05:30",
       "@version" => 1,
        "message" => "Assigned value 1 to the variable : X",
    "logger_name" => "com.example.logstash.Variable",
    "thread_name" => "pool-1-thread-1",
          "level" => "INFO",
    "level_value" => 20000,
       "HOSTNAME" => "pnibinkj-W7-1",
           "uuid" => "ab17b842-8348-4474-98e4-8bc2b8dd6781",
           "host" => "127.0.0.1"
}
{
     "@timestamp" => "2015-04-01T10:23:37.863+05:30",
       "@version" => 1,
        "message" => "Assigned value 1 to the variable : Y",
    "logger_name" => "com.example.logstash.Variable",
    "thread_name" => "pool-1-thread-2",
          "level" => "INFO",
    "level_value" => 20000,
       "HOSTNAME" => "pnibinkj-W7-1",
           "uuid" => "d5513e4c-de3b-4144-87e4-87b077ac8056",
           "host" => "127.0.0.1"
}
```

There are 2 UUIDs

"d5513e4c-de3b-4144-87e4-87b077ac8056" for "Y = 1"
"ab17b842-8348-4474-98e4-8bc2b8dd6781" for "X = 1"

There are two other messages for each UUID. I want to combine them into a single event.

I am not sure, how to write the multiline filter for this case.

```html
filter {
  multiline {
    pattern => "."
    what => "previous"
    stream_identity => "%{uuid}"
  }
}
```

"pattern" and "what" are required fields, it seems. What should I provide for these fields. How do I use Stream Identity?

Please point me in right direction.

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to combine your messages (see multiline{} filter, which supports stream_identity), and then a regular query would return the appropriate message.

Comment: How do I use the stream_identity? Can you show one example?

Answer (score 0):

this should be possible using the kibana filters if X is some unique value, but with the logs in the format shown you'd need to use the multiline filter to join the entries together.

With that in place, you could probably use a query something like

```
message: "X=1"
```

Comment: How do I use the multiline filter to achieve this? Can you show one example?